# Secondary Sort on List.Sort method

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I have a Generic List that I am trying to implement a secondary sort type. I am able to get it to sort fine by one type, but having trouble getting the secondary sort.

Here is what im working with:

When Im calling sort:

```
List<Totals> totals = new LoadTotalList();
totals.Sort(Totals.Status);
```

Here is the Totals Class:

```
public class Totals
{
  public string Status { get; set; } 
  public string Total { get; set; } 
  public string Cost { get; set; } 

  public static Comparison<Totals> StatusComp = 
delegate(Totals item1, Totals item2)
{
 return item1.Status.CompareTo(item2.Status);
};

  public static Comparison<Totals> CostComp = 
delegate(Totals item1, Totals item2)
{
 return item1.Cost.CompareTo(item2.Cost);
};


}
```

Ive tried sorting the firt type, then sorting the second type, but cant seem to get secondary sort type. I know it can be done w/ Linq using an OrderBy clause then ThenBy Clause. But do I have any other Options.   Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy enough to create a `Comparison<T>` which has a primary comparison and then a secondary one:

```
public static class Comparisons
{
    public static Comparison<T> Then<T>(this Comparison<T> primary,
                                        Comparison<T> secondary)
    {
        // TODO: Nullity validation
        return (x, y) =>
        {
            int first = primary(x, y);
            return first != 0 ? first : secondary(x, y);
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
list.Sort(Totals.StatusComp.Then(Totals.CostComp));
```

(You can do the same for `IComparer<T>` easily too.)

Comment: Thanks Jon! You got me up and working. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Jon, Shouldn't the class be static since its an extension method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [overload of `List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) which allows to use a custom comparison delegate:

```
totals.Sort((t1, t2) => {
    if (t1.Status != t2.Status) return t1.Status.CompareTo(t2.Status);
    else return t1.Cost.CompareTo(t2.Cost);
});
```

Comment: This is a great alternative as well. Both are great answers. Thanks Tim

Comment: Note that `!=` always uses an *ordinal* comparison. It's entirely possible for strings to be non-equal under an ordinal comparison, but for `CompareTo` to return 0. (See the docs for `string.CompareTo` for an example.)